# Using CakePdf with Mpdf return BODY error

Tags: cakephp, mpdf

I just installed CakePdf to produce PDF file. I would like to use Mpdf engine instead of WkHtmlToPdf.

I have already add `public $components = array('RequestHandler');` in my `FormsController` controller file. Also I've already created the layouts and view files like so `app/View/Layouts/pdf/default.ctp` and `app/View/Forms/pdf/view.ctp`.

The following is how I create my code:

```
<?php
// the rest of the codes

public function view($id=null) {
  $kid = $this->FormU5mrn->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('FormU5mrn.id' => $id),
  ));

  $filename = 'U5MR-' . $kid['FormU5mrn']['ref_no'] . '.pdf';

  $this->pdfConfig = array(
    'orientation' => 'portrait',
    'filename' => $filename
  );

  $this->set(compact('kid'));
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: BODY [APP/Plugin/CakePdf/Vendor/mpdf/mpdf.php, line 14242]
Notice (8): Undefined index: BODY>>ID>> [APP/Plugin/CakePdf/Vendor/mpdf/mpdf.php, line 14288]
Notice (8): Undefined offset: -1 [APP/Plugin/CakePdf/Vendor/mpdf/mpdf.php, line 14421]
Notice (8): Undefined property: mPDF::$hasOC [APP/Plugin/CakePdf/Vendor/mpdf/mpdf.php, line 27777]
Notice (8): Undefined property: mPDF::$hasOC [APP/Plugin/CakePdf/Vendor/mpdf/mpdf.php, line 27879]
Notice (8): Undefined property: mPDF::$hasOC [APP/Plugin/CakePdf/Vendor/mpdf/mpdf.php, line 8772]
```

Comment: ahhh... it seems that mPDF has an error... not really CakePdf issues. To fix the issue, just type `error_reporting(0);` in your controller. Closing this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the debug value from 1/2 -> 0 in app/Config/core.php

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

Comment: thanks @ArunJain, but I'm now on development server. Once on production, will set debug=0.

Comment: The best thing I did to edit mpdf.php and put the condition if(isset()... in the same lines where warnings came... it worked for me even on debugging mode.